# Having trouble receiving data back from post using php fopen with a stream context

Tags: php, http, http-post, fopen

I've been trying to figure out where my error is in this particular function.
It's very similar to a posted function online with a few minor tweaks.  Anyway, I have a specific url in the variable $PAYMENTPAGE->ipa_url.  I'm trying to post to this and simply have the return data be a die('test') to verify the connection is going through properly.
Instead I keep getting a blank page.

I have managed to get it working using the curl extension but would prefer to simply use streams as they work out of the box with any extensions.  I know the connection is being made, because I was receiving exception errors which I fixed, but now I'm just having trouble figuring out why no information is being returned from the post.

```
function doPostRequest($url, $data, $optional_headers = null)
{
    $params = array('http' => array(
                'method' => 'POST',
                'content' => $data
             ));
    if ($optional_headers !== null) {
        $params['http']['header'] = $optional_headers;
    }
    $ctx = stream_context_create($params);
    $get_stream = true;
    try{
        $fp = @fopen($url, 'rb', false, $ctx);
        if (!$fp) {
             throw new Exception("Problem creating stream from $url, \n\t".implode("\n\t", error_get_last()));
        }
        $response = @stream_get_contents($fp);
        if ($response === false) {
           throw new Exception("Problem reading data from $url, \n\t".implode("\n\t", error_get_last()));
        }
        $get_stream = false;
    } catch(Exception $e){
        mcFatal("Error(".date('Y-m-d h:i:s').'):'.$e->getMessage()."\n");
    }


    if($get_stream){
        return false;
    }

    return $response;
}
```

Comment: I wonder if `stream_get_contents` is throwing any warning. Remove the error suppressing `@` and make sure your `error_reporting` is low enough to see it (as well as `display_errors` or `log_errors`). Also, I don't know if `fopen` ing a url with binary flag is expected behavior? In any case see if replacing `fopen`+`stream_get_contents` with `file_get_contents` makes any difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Ubuntu: This is a bug in the PHP version Ubuntu ships. See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/php5/+bug/650779 for more details.

Comment: My personal machine is Ubuntu, but the script is being run from a network server running freebsd 8.0.  My guess is there is a similar bug occurring on that OS.

Answer (score -1):

Is there any reason why you are not using an http protocol library, such as cURL? It handles the streams for you, and can produce information in the event of an error.

```
function doPostRequest($url, $data, $optional_headers = null) 
{
   $ch = curl_init();
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

   //include array of additional headers
   if (count($optional_headers)) {
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $optional_headers);
   }

   return curl_exec($ch);
}
```

Comment: It's unlikely, but in the event that curl isn't installed or there is an issue with an upgrade it would be nice to not have to rely on curl.

Comment: While I partially agree, I would consider cURL an essential extension. Otherwise, your going to be re-implementing the HTTP protocol to parse the results. Regardless, I don't see anything specifically wrong with your code so it's tough to debug (which is why we use such extensions in the first place ;))

Comment: The question were about fopen not cURL , I was using cURL in past but I find it harder to opimize compaing to other simple alternatives .